# cannot access files in trash previously on external harddrive

Tags: terminal, trash

I have no problem making a list of all files in the trash provided those files were previously on the main harddrive, but when those files were previously on an external harddrive I can't access them with Terminal or Python. At first, I ran into permission errors but I've since changed the permissions.  For example,

```
ls /users/me/.Trash
```

will print out what is actually in the trash.  But when I do the following:

```
ls /volumes/edrive/.Trashes
```

I just get `503` even though there is a file in there not named 503. For some reason the trash folder is called .Trashes when it's on an external hard-drive.  I'm also trying it with Python which is what I want to use anyway:

```
import os
os.listdir('/volumes/edrive/.Trashes')
```

Outputs

```
['503']
```

Answer (score 5):

The drive-wide Trash contains the deleted files of all users, with one directory per numerical User ID. Run

```
ls -l /Volumes/edrive/.Trashes
```

to see that `503` is a directory, and

```
ls -l /Volumes/edrive/.Trashes/503
```

to see its content.

PS: You can see your own user id by running `id -u` . If it is *not* `503` you'll need to run `sudo ls -l /Volumes/edrive/.Trashes/503` instead.

Comment: `id -u` to print current user id